# WooCommerce- Change variables (eg Size) at checkout/review order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a one-click-checkout page, and the product variables (eg Size, colour) needs to feature at the checkout page itself.

I have modified the "review-order.php" template without success.

My attempt was-

`<?php echo($available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();) ?>`

How can I add an option to change the product variable at the "review-order.php" page?